# how i can make my variable equal any element of my Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, random, equals

I have

```
String[] country={"USA","ks a","UK","France"};
```

I have a variable `String z`.

I want to say

```
if(z.equals(any element of my array (USA or ks or France)
```

but randomly:

```
if(z.equals(country[i]){
    Doing action any code
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if z is an element in your array?  Or if its a randomly picked element in that array?

Comment: ok i build string array for the right answers ,i want to code if my button.gettext () .tostring().equal()any element from this array do action

Comment: no no sorry z is an element in my array not random

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use

```
   if ( Arrays.asList(country).contains(z)) {
         // your code
    }
```

Comment: i don't understand is array list necessary?in my case how do it?

Comment: `Arrays` is `java.util.Arrays` class to do what you want you should first create a   `java.util.List` based on your array after that use the `contains` method of List to check if the parameter passed exist in the list

Comment: Creating a List first is absolutely NOT what you should do.  Its extra allocations and overhead.  The right answer is to write a loop over the existing array.

Comment: Yes of course but i don't think he wants to loop it's trivial!!!!!

Comment: mr Master mind thank you very mutch your amazing method heals my problem. if ( Arrays.asList(country).contains(z)) {
         // your code
    }

Comment: you are welcome could you please choose the answer as the good one please?

Comment: how? i do that iam new tell me and i will

Comment: on the left of the answer under the vote there is a grey check logo make it green

Comment: can take photo with capture and send i do not understand

Comment: ok i found it done my friend?:)